# Python - Added new class method but it does not seem to exist to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class.  I added a new method to the class, saved the file, closed the file, and the destroyed any instances that was previously created from the object.  When I try to create a new instance of the object and call the new method, I get an attribute not found error.  I made sure to add a docstring to my method, but when I use help([class]), the method doesn't appear there, either.  I've tried closing down my IDE completely and starting fresh.  What's going on?  Why is my new method not registering?

I am using python 3 and PyCharm as my IDE.

Comment: Can you run dir(class) and see the method there?

Comment: Have you tried running from the command line?

Comment: did you create a class without any params? I.e. you forget the `(self, ...) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to exit out the IDE completely.  After I did this, the changes registered.